# Google Drive API get files in specific folder in Laravel

Tags: laravel, api

i am using the following code to get files from folder id. But I am not getting the files id instead empty array returning.

```
 putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=C:\Users\new\Downloads\zonefunnel1.json');
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();

$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
$res=$service->files->listFiles();
//print_r($res);
$folderId="0B_bZZilaXPR4WkNvdFpMZmdneEU";
  $optParams = array(
        'pageSize' => 10,
        'fields' => "nextPageToken, files(contentHints/thumbnail,fileExtension,iconLink,id,name,size,thumbnailLink,webContentLink,webViewLink,mimeType,parents)",
        'q' => "'".$folderId."' in parents"
        );
  $results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);
  print_r($results);die();
```

I am getting the following,

```
Google_Service_Drive_FileList Object ( [collection_key:protected] => files [filesType:protected] => Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile [filesDataType:protected] => array [incompleteSearch] => [kind] => [nextPageToken] => [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array ( ) [modelData:protected] => Array ( ) [processed:protected] => Array ( ) [files] => Array ( ) )
```

Please help me I have spent one week time for this.But not able to sort it out.

Regards,
Rekha

Answer (score 0):

```
$files_list = $service->files->listFiles(array())->getFiles($optParams);
```

Comment: While it’s acceptable to provide code-only answers, it’s often more useful for the community if you can also provide an explanation of the code and help people understand _why_ it addresses the problem. That can reduce the number of follow-up questions, and  help new developers understand the underlying concepts. Would you mind updating your question with additional detail?